# Consulta hacia columna JSON sin resultados (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Qué tal? Estoy usando *mysql 10.4.24-MariaDB* y tengo una tabla:

```
create table player_groups(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    characters json,
);
```

inserto:

```
insert into player_groups 
values(1, '{"matrix":[ {"id":"11"}, {"id":"12" }, {"id":"13" }]}' );
```

Pero al realizar está consulta para obtener el id con valor "13" no obtengo resultados:
`0 row(s) returned` existiendo el valor:

```
SELECT *
FROM player_groups
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(characters, '$.matrix[*].id'), "13");
```

tampoco:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(characters,'$.matrix[*].id') AS ids 
FROM player_groups 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(characters,'$.matrix[*].id') = "13";
```

Aquí retorna todos los valores de los id... pero claro, solo busco filtrar condicionalmente:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(characters,'$.matrix[*].id') AS ids 
FROM player_groups;
```

No logro entender el error en la consulta, por ende no puedo consultar/actualizar/borrar ¿En que fallo? agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Aunque usar JSON en un campo de una tabla MySQL puede parecer una buena idea, si vas a realizar búsquedas en su contenido vas a perjudicar el rendimiento de la base de datos porque por cada búsqueda el SGBD tendrá que hacer un barrido completo de TODA la tabla. En cambio, si esa información estuviera en una tabla separada y el campo `id` fuera un índice, solo se obtendrían los registros coincidentes sin tener que comprobar todos y cada uno de los registros existentes en la tabla `player_groups`.

Comment: Si este tipo de búsquedas son puntuales (en un formulario de buscador, por ejemplo), se puede asumir la sobrecarga, pero si forma parte de una consulta recurrente o frecuente, entonces deberías plantearte diseñar las tablas adecuadamente o tendrás problemas de escalabilidad (en rendimiento) conforme tu aplicación crezca.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás experimentando se debe a la forma en que estás utilizando la función JSON_CONTAINS y JSON_EXTRACT en tu consulta.

En la consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM player_groups
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(characters, '$.matrix[*].id'), "13");
```

Estás extrayendo una matriz de objetos JSON de la columna 'characters' y luego verificando si alguno de los objetos contiene el valor "13". Sin embargo, la función JSON_EXTRACT en este caso devuelve una matriz de valores y no un solo valor, lo que provoca que JSON_CONTAINS falle.

Para solucionar esto, debes usar la función JSON_SEARCH en lugar de JSON_EXTRACT para buscar el valor "13" dentro de la matriz 'matrix':

```
SELECT *
FROM player_groups
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(characters, 'one', '13', NULL, '$.matrix[*].id') IS NOT NULL;
```

Esta consulta busca el valor "13" dentro de la matriz 'matrix' y devuelve todas las filas que contienen el valor. La función JSON_SEARCH devuelve el camino del objeto JSON que contiene el valor "13", y luego verificamos si es diferente de NULL para asegurarnos de que el valor existe en la matriz.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por responder. El resultado es: ``'{"matrix":[ {"id":"11"}, {"id":"12" }, {"id":"13" }]}' `` lo cual no resuelve mi pregunta, es decir, debería ser la respuesta: `` {"id":"13" }``

Comment: @LILOU, por favor, [edita tu pregunta (pulsando en este enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/583379/edit) indicando cómo esperas que sea el resultado. Si no lo dejas claramente indicado en tu pregunta, es imposible conocer ese dato.

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.